# Einstein Bot, change language in snippet code

Tags: einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots

I created a multi lingual Einstein Bot and I want to change the language in snippet code, because I have several website in different language.
I edit this field:

> `embedded_svc.settings.language = 'es';`

But it changes only the pre-compiled form of the bot. How can I change the dialogues language in snippet code?

Answer (score 0):

This Dialog Translations feature is not applicable/available for Standard Bots. Salesforce product team logged a Document Bug #W-12245559 internally to update the documentation according to which:

> Issue: Standard bots with multi-language enabled are seeing system dialogs in the footer menu not translated.
> To add in [page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bots_service_language_define.htm&type=5): In Standard Bots with multiple languages enabled, dialogs assigned to the Bot Options Menu only show in the bot primary language.

Also, work item #W-12234009 has been created internally to explore on support for translated Bot Options Menu in Enhanced Bots.

Note that there is no scheduled Build or ETA on when this feature would be available at the moment.